# Where can I post some plugins I wrote

Tags: support, self-promotion

i want to tell the users who are searching for a method to create links based on the root path of their webapp, but i don't know where to post.
I read in a comment, that there is a blog page or something else for it.

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" - This doesn't sound like "i disagree" don't you think it's cowardly to hind behind downvote without leave a comment WHY he downvoted?!

Comment: In addition to what @CodeCaster said, this question actually *does* show "no research effort". Read the [Help] for information on what to ask and how to answer.

Comment: due to my rep, you can see im new here... i already read this, but i still wonder about the titles... nvm still the question is open why to disagree to a question, where to help others...

Comment: You just spelled out the reason why I downvoted: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". You don't seem to have consulted the help center which would tell you that SO is not for posting blog posts; it should also have been trivial to find out that there is no blog where random users can post stuff. It's a tiny bit unclear what exactly you're asking and if it could theoretically be turned into a self-answered question. And of course it's not excactly useful to the general public as it seems to be based on a misunderstanding and lack of research.

Comment: @AndrewBarber to understand your comment... you dont help others or share your solutions with them? very kindly

Comment: @Mephiztopheles That's what we do here, yes. What we *don't* do here is promote ourselves or our work.

Comment: you missunderstand me. I have my hp and my repository in github to promote. My decision to write this question was to help peaople who are searching for the solution to get root path, because it was long a problem for me.

Comment: @Mephiztopheles we _help_ people in a rather special way: by curating a repository of useful, specific, high-quality posts in question/answer format. At least that's the SO mission statement. Your planned post, while probably helpful in a way, does not fit that mission statement, thus the only meaningful answer as to where to post it would be "somewhere else".

Comment: "curating a repository of useful, specific, high-quality posts in question/answer format" - Where is the difference in what i want to do? ( Serious question)

Comment: You are here to promote something. That is the difference. Feel free to answer any questions **others** might have to ask about your software, but do not try to self-promote your software on stackoverflow.

Comment: No, that's not what i want... but.. nvm ... i will never again ask if there are so much people who better downvote instead to think about it and leave a helpful reply

Comment: The difference is in the q/a part as well as the _specific_ part. If you're able to formulate a question that is specific (= not too broad) and otherwise on-topic (no recommendation, etc), that can be succinctly answered by you, and is potentially useful to people, you can create a [self-answered post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). But it sounds like your post could only be a recommendation question (Q: "what can I use to create these links?" - A: "use this plugin") which would not be on-topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That doesn't sound like the kind of thing that would be on-topic for Stack Overflow. You should post your plugins on GitHub or another code-sharing site so that people searching will find them there. Questions asking for plugins on Stack Overflow would be closed as off-topic.

Comment: I just read that there is a blog, so i asked.
I don't know all of Stack Overflows features. (And i don't get why my question is not useful or unclear....)

Comment: @Mephiztopheles There is a blog, but only Stack Exchange employees can post there. It's not for general use. I guess the downvotes are for wanting to use Stack Overflow to promote your plugins? That's generally frowned on.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but they're likely also for jumping straight to posting what people see as an obvious question rather than reading the help center to learn what Stack Overflow is and isn't for.

Comment: @sphanley Yeah, you're right. "Doesn't show research effort" is probably the reason.